# Bypass invalid SSL certificate for Kestrel server displayed in WebView2

Tags: .net-core, webview2

**Given**

- WPF app starts Kestrel server
- Kestrel listens to `http://0.0.0.0:5000` and `https://0.0.0.0:6000`
- Kestrel is pointed to static HTML file `index.html`
- WPF shows browser control WebView2 which is pointed to `https://127.0.0.1:6000/index.html`

**Results**

- If WebView2 is pointed to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html` everything works fine
- If WebView2 is pointed to `https://127.0.0.1:6000/index.html` I get an error about untrusted certificate

**Question**

- Is it possible to disable or ignore SSL validation for localhost in Kestrel or WebView2

Windows settings shouldn't be touched, e.g. marking "localhost" certificate as trusted in "msmc" or generating self-signed certificates, because this WPF app is supposed to run on different computers.

In other words, there must be an easier way than described in this [article](https://cmatskas.com/enforcing-https-only-traffic-with-asp-net-core-and-kestrel/).

**Kestrel**

```
public class WebServer
{
  public static Task Run()
  {
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().Build();

    var urls = new[]
    {
      "http://0.0.0.0:7000",
      "https://0.0.0.0:8000"
    };

    var environment = WebHost
      .CreateDefaultBuilder(new string[0])
      .UseConfiguration(configuration)
      .UseUrls(urls)
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseIISIntegration()
      .UseStartup<WebStartup>();

    return environment.Build().RunAsync();
  }
}

public class WebStartup
{
  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  public WebStartup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
      configuration.RootPath = "index.html";
    });
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseHsts();
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
  }
}
```

**WebView2 Control in WPF**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  WebServer.Run();

  InitializeComponent();

  WebView.Source = new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:6000/index.html"); // HTTP on 5000 works, HTTPS 6000 - no
  WebView.NavigationCompleted += (object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args) =>
  {
    WebView.InvalidateVisual();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The WebView2 doesn't currently directly expose that feature. If you like, you can open an issue in [WebView2 Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues) and we can make a feature request.

As a workaround you might try using the [CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/dotnet/0-9-538/microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2#calldevtoolsprotocolmethodasync) to invoke the [Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors DevTools Protocol method](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security/#method-setIgnoreCertificateErrors). However, I haven't tried setIgnoreCertificateErrors out, and its also marked experimental so not positive it will work in the manner you'd like.

Comment: I can confirm that this works (WebView2 1.0.818.41) and this line of code `var result = await webView.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors", "{\"ignore\": true}");`
result is an empty json object and I placed this code inside the `webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

extensions

```
 public static CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions AddArg(this CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options, string arg)
        {
            options.AdditionalBrowserArguments += $" {arg}";
            return options;
        }
        public static CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions AddArg(this CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options, string arg,string value)
        {
            options.AdditionalBrowserArguments += $" {arg}={value}";
            return options;
        }
```

manual config

```
 var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(userDataFolder: "Cache",
                    options:new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions()
                        .AddArg("--ignore-certificate-errors")
                    );
                await _webBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?